# Unable to use Test Users for posting through Open Graph

Tags: testing, publish, facebook-opengraph

I'm following the official guide to using Open Graph Beta and am able to post an action using my username (I'm a developer of the app). However, when I try to use one of the test users I get the following error message:

```
{  
  "error":
    {
      "message" : "Error validating application.",
      "type" : "OAuthException"
    }
}
```

For reference, I'm using the code from the Open Graph Dashboard (where it says "Get Code" next to the custom action). It has the following format, where angle brackets are placeholders for actual values:

```
curl -F 'access_token=<token>' \
     -F '<obj>=http://samples.ogp.me/<obj_id>' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/<namespace>:<action>'
```

How I can publish actions using one of my test users?

Comment: Please post more code about the call your making - which generates this response.

Comment: I updated my original post with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still unable to get the test users created through the dashboard to work. However, test users created manually work just fine.
I've followed the instructions given at:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

Comment: It looks like test accounts created through dashboard have the app approved but without any permissions. It makes sense since you don't usually specify app scope in your app but in the code.